# AddOLEObject does not accept my filename variant

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have the following VBA subroutine in a word document:

```
Private Sub InsertPDF(fullFileName, displayName)
    Selection.InlineShapes.AddOLEObject ClassType:="AcroExch.Document.DC", _
        FileName:=fullFileName, _
        LinkToFile:=False, _
        DisplayAsIcon:=True, _
        IconFileName:="C:\Windows\Installer\{AC76BA86-7AD7-1033-7B44-AC0F074E4100}\PDFFile_8.ico", _
        IconIndex:=0, _
        IconLabel:=displayName
End Sub
```

When I run it, it errors with the message: "word cannot obtain the data for the <file> link".

While debugging the locals window show the variable with the correct path, which is evidenced by copying it directly from there and hard-coding `fullFileName` in the routine to the value set, e.g. "C:\users\user\file.pdf" the code works. The Type shows as "Variant/String", which I believe it correct. The variable `displayName` is the same type and it does not need to be hard-coded.

I have tried to sanity check the string by running it through Trim and CStr without success.

What am I doing wrong, or what else can I do to narrow down the problem?

Comment: Your code works as is, as long as the path and filename are correct.  Otherwise, the same error message occurs.

Comment: I would put a line at the beginning of the Sub: `Debug.Print fullFileName = "C:\users\user\file.pdf"`, and see if it prints `True`. If not, then the two strings were not really the same.

Comment: @z32a7ul Good catch; the debug.print says false but I couldn't see where they differ. I stepped through the var char by char and found there are 2 hdden characters at the end; probably a CRLF. Once I stripped those the code worked as expected. Something so simple tripped me up for so long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a trailing CRLF at the end of the string. I normalised the string on input like so; note the additional line at the top of the sub:

```
Private Sub InsertPDF(fullFileName, displayName)
    fullFileName = Replace(fullFileName, vbCrLf, "")
    Selection.InlineShapes.AddOLEObject ClassType:="AcroExch.Document.DC", _
        FileName:=fullFileName, _
        LinkToFile:=False, _
        DisplayAsIcon:=True, _
        IconFileName:="C:\Windows\Installer\{AC76BA86-7AD7-1033-7B44-AC0F074E4100}\PDFFile_8.ico", _
        IconIndex:=0, _
        IconLabel:=displayName
End Sub
```

Comment: @OscarSun Yes, it is solved.